# Populating Flex combobox from XML returned via web service

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to populate a combobox in Flex 3 from XML returned via a web service.

Here is the code:

```
     <mx:WebService id="Services" 
    wsdl="http://10.10.15.4///WebService.asmx?wsdl"
    useProxy="false">
    <mx:operation   name="getAccounts"
                    showBusyCursor="true"
                    fault="showErrorDialog(event)">                         
    </mx:operation>
    </mx:WebService>
```

And the code for the combobox:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="accountPicker" labelField="Account" dataProvider="{Services.getAccounts.lastResult.Root.Node.Account}"/>
```

My XML that is returned looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Node>
       <Account>Account1</Account>
    </Node>
   <Node>
       <Account>Account2</Account>
    </Node>
</Root>
```

What am i doing wrong here? currently the combobox is blank. If i remove the .Root.Node.Account from the dataProvider then it returns [Object Object].

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. When dealing with e4x, the root is implicit so you just want `xmlObject.Node.Account`
2. `Node.Account` gives you an XMLList of account nodes. These nodes don't have an "Account" property so `labelField` isn't going to work. If you just leave out the `labelField`, the combo box will call toString() on each element, which is automatically the inner text.

So what you want is:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="accountPicker" dataProvider="{Services.getAccounts.lastResult.Node.Account}" />
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. I changed it to:     `<mx:ComboBox id="accountPicker" labelField="Account" dataProvider="{(Services.getCrmAccounts.lastResult).Root.Node}"/>` and it worked. Could this be due to the XML been returned?

Comment: @CameronEdwards I'd check the value of lastResult to make sure it's what you expect. The debugger is your friend. That code worked fine in my test just now.